# Цикл for по столбцам датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, for

Есть датафрейм:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'ab':['abc','bde'],'ac':['abcc','bdec'],'Sum':[1,2]})`
```

список столбцов:

```
lst = ['ab','ac']
```

Нужно применить к этим столбцам функцию в цикле for:

```
for i in lst:
   a.i = a.i.str.replace('b', '89')
```

но выдаёт ошибку. Пробовал варианты:

```
for i in lst:
    a.globals()[i] = a.globals()[i].str.replace('b', '89')
```

и

```
for i in lst:
    eval('a.' + globals()[i]) = eval('a.' + globals()[i]).str.replace('b', '89')
```

но тоже ошибка. Как правильно написать цикл `for` по списку названий колонок датафрейма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно этот список использовать для индексирования по столбцам

```
    ab    ac  Sum
0  abc  abcc    1
1  bde  bdec    2


a[lst] = a[lst].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('b', '89'))

     ab     ac  Sum
0  a89c  a89cc    1
1  89de  89dec    2
```

---

можно сделать проще

```
a[lst] = a[lst].replace('b', '89', regex=True)
```

но при рельных данных надо учитывать, что выражения для замены будут интерпретироваться как регулярные выражения, а с regex=False, замена будет происходить только в случае полного совпадения содержимого ячейки с образцом

Answer (score 2):

```py
for i in lst:
   a.i = a.i.str.replace('b', '89')

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i'
```

Нужно помнить, что обращение к колонкам датафрейма как к атрибутам через точку - это не стабильная фича, а просто приятное дополнение к основным, более правильным способам, имеющая много ограничений. Кроме того, тут вы фактически обращаетесь к столбцу с именем `i`, а не к тому столбцу, имя которого находится в переменной `i`.

Правильный (но устаревший) метод - это обращение через индексацию (квадратные скобки):

```py
for i in lst:
   a[i] = a[i].str.replace('b', '89')
```

Но самый правильный и современный способ - это использовать метод `.loc`, с указанием строк и столбцов, к которым вы обращаетесь (в данном случае это все строки, для этого используется срез `:`):

```py
for i in lst:
   a.loc[:,i] = a[:,i].str.replace('b', '89')
```

Но вообще работать с датафреймами в цикле не очень хорошо, лучше использовать другие методы, описанные, например, в другом ответе на этот вопрос.